# Resolving urls on a Wordpress server using React

Tags: php, html, wordpress, react-router

I'm working on creating a new React-based site to replace an old WordPress site. I have been creating directories within the wordpress server for the new sections I have been making. domain.org/about, for example, will go to the react files stored in the about directory. No problems there. The issue I am having now is for more complicated urls. I have set up react-router to handle lots of events by using an id to pull in information on a specific event. domain.org/events/event123, for example, should display information on event123. In development this works fine, localhost:3000/events/event123 will display event123. On the wordpress server, however, I get an error. I realize that this is because there is no event123 directory within the events directory on the wordpress server.

How can I configure wordpress to handle these urls? I realize I need to set something up so that any url that begins with domain.org/events will go to the react files in the events directory, but how I go about doing this while still passing along the event123 I do not know. Any help is appreciated. Apologies if my description is a bit confusing.

EDIT: I should add that the old parts of the site and new parts of the site have no connection to each other, other than the fact that they are hosted on the same server. Once the new site has enough content on it it will be moved to a new server and the wordpress site will be shut down.

Comment: Hey David, could you please provide me .htaccess file which is located in root directory  of your wordpress site and how you are going to integrate react with wp. You are going to create wp theme, plugin in backend or it should work separately from wp and you want to use wp as your api ?

Comment: Hi Davit, I think you are on the right track with an .htaccess file. The root .htaccess file works the way it should, but I'm guessing that I should have an additional one within the events directory that can handle urls like domain.org/events/event123?

Comment: In wp .htaccess sends all requests to index.php file in root folder. So for example if enter following url  domain.org/events/event123 it will not go to event folder because of htaccess wp will read index.php in rooter folder will initialize query string like this category=events and post_name=event123

Comment: Here is link that can help you to rewrite htaccess which will  allow apache to read events subdirectory
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40